# How to result sql query ORDER BY ID DESC to more than 1 div

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have been busy with a blog system and i am currently trying to output the sql data order by id desc into different divs (cols) like the latest 3 blogs, the other older blogs has to be on the page order by id desc below. 
I hope someone can help me.

```
<?php 
   $postRow = $db->query("SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, imgBackground, imgNewspost FROM blog_posts WHERE postID = '$postID'");
?>
```

First code, connection to the database is OK.
The first 3 cols at the top of the page are like these:

```
<a href="index.html" class="collink">
    <div class="sub-col col"> 
                <?php
    try {

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, imgBackground, imgNewspost FROM blog_posts WHERE postID ="7" ');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo "<img class='imgtopnews'src='".$row['imgNewspost']."'>";
            echo '<div>';
                echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
                echo '<p>Gepost op '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';                
                echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Lees verder</a></p>';                
            echo '</div>';

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>


    </div>  
</a>
```

Last but not least all older blogs are at the page below the 3 cols:

```
    <?php
    try {

        $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate, imgBackground, imgNewspost FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

            echo '<div class="nieuwscol">';
                echo '<div class="newstitle"><p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></p></div>';
                echo '<div class="newsdate"><p>Gepost op '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p></div>';
                echo "<img class='imgnews'src='".$row['imgNewspost']."'>";
                echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';                
                echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Lees verder</a></p>';                
            echo '</div>';

        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: If anyone can help me, I got teamviewer or mail us: eggelitegamegroup@gmail.com

Comment: If you're running PDO you should really put your logic into class files rather than into the actual files

Answer (score 0):

So here's how i'd do what you're trying to do:

I'd firstly set up a class file for blog ie (class.blog.php)

You need to extend the database connect class which I have branded DBClass currently for demo purposes. You'll also need to `require_once()` the file of the database connection file.

Here is the blog class:

```
class blog extends DBClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__contruct();
    }

    public function getBlog()
    {
        $stmt = "SELECT count(*) FROM `blog_posts`";
        $res = $this->prepare($stmt);
        $res->execute();

        $count = $res->fetchColumn();

        if ($count > 0) {
            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `blog_posts` ORDER BY `postID` DESC";
            $res = $this->prepare($stmt);
            $res->execute();

            while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        }
    }
}
```

Then within the blog file you'd need to do the following (my demo purpose here) I'm sure you'll be able to adjust accordingly to suit:

`require_once('class.blog.php');`

```
$blog = new blog();

$blogInfo = $blog->getBlog();

foreach ($blogInfo as $row)
{
    echo
    "<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                $row->imgNewpost
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h1>
                    <a href='viewpost.php?id=$row->postID'>$row->postTitle</a>
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}
```

If you want these as a `<div>` just remove the table and echo out the divs instead.

Comment: This looks good, but somehow I am getting errors all the time

Comment: What errors are you running into? It'll need tweaks but this is the foundation of how your PHP code should look and run